# Tennat scoped email urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In a Rails 6 app, I need to scope the URLs generated within my emails to the current tenant (I'm using Apartment for that).

So, A correct URL looks like `http://localhost:3000/tenant_name/dashboard`

The tenant is added to the URL using a `Middleware` similar to https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/gorails-episode-234/blob/master/lib/account_middleware.rb

```
class AccountMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  # http://example.com/12345/projects
  def call(env)
    _, organization_name, request_path = env["REQUEST_PATH"].split('/', 3)

    if true
      if organization = Organization.find_by(name: organization_name)
        Current.organization = organization
      else
        return [302, { "Location" => "/" }, []]
      end

      env["SCRIPT_NAME"]  = "/#{organization_name}"
      env["PATH_INFO"]    = "/#{request_path}"
      env["REQUEST_PATH"] = "/#{request_path}"
      env["REQUEST_URI"]  = "/#{request_path}"
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

With the following

```
#/config/routes.rb
get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#show'
```

If I simply use `root_url` I get `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` which doesn't work.

After trying several approaches, I came up with

```
"#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:protocol]}://#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}/#{Apartment::Tenant.current}#{dashboard_url(only_path: true)}"
```

Which works but is pretty ugly.

Any ideas of how I can make it better?

Comment: IMO if you find yourself needing to add a segment key when using `_url` instead of `_path` (in your case you are adding the `tenant_name` segment key), then you should add the segment key to your original route definition. Assuming that it is inferred through something like `current_user` in your application. If not, could you add more to your question about how `/dashboard` works

Comment: Hi there, see reference to Middleware. Thanks

Comment: Knowing that you are using middleware helps...are you able to show us your implementation?

Comment: I use `organization` instead of `account` but it's basically identical to the one on GoRails repo.

Comment: Please share your implementation. If the only thing you changed was the class name in the middleware class then the obvious issue is that the `tenant_name` will never be set because the GoRails implementation requires a numerical id. In addition, I just watched the GoRails episode you are referring to and there are other areas that could cause an issue.

Comment: Here my middleware